# How to change position of Container inside Stack?

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, containers, material-design

Im trying to displaying a button inside my stack but it not getting the correct position.  The button is the reply  Button . I added a foot how it looks at the moment you can check it what I want is displaying it on the right side of the window at the bottom with a bit of spacing between bottom and the button.
Hope anyone can help. if you need more information please leave a comment .

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    try {
      return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: mystreamofallvideos,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData &&
                  snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return PageView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                    controller:
                        PageController(initialPage: 0, viewportFraction: 1),
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      DocumentSnapshot videos = snapshot.data.docs[index];

                      return Stack(children: [
                        Videoplayeritem(widget.videoid),

                        Column(children: [
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 100,
                              child: Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                children: [
                                  IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(
                                        Icons.close,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        size: 35,
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                      }),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 190,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            width: 210,
                            height: 94,
                            //color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),

                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () => sharevideo(
                                  widget.videoid, videos.data()['id']),
                              child: Icon(Icons.reply,
                                  size: 55, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ]),

                        //starssonthe right
                      ]);
                    });
              } else {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            }),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      e.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

This is how it looks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4J78.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in an align and add a padding to the bottom:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
  child: Container(
  height: 40,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
  child: OutlinedButton(
           onPressed: () {},
           child: Text('mybutton'),
           ),
 )
```

Comment: That was not working it still show me the container on the same height. the position just changed of the icon to right bottom inside the container . So the container should be to the bottom right of the widget

Comment: So you wrap the widget that is directly to the stack.

Comment: When I do that then nothing happened Itried on every place its not working

Comment: You need organize better your code, it should works.

Comment: You can check my code update thats how it loos now i also tried to wrap the colum with the align its not workling

Comment: the videoplayerutem is a full screen video and then on the top left shoud be the close button snd bottom right the reply buttom. The close button is correct but the reply not

Comment: to the stack works you need to place each element that need positione in the root of the stack, the container of the share buttom is inside of the Column not in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your container with either `Positioned` or `Align` widgets

like :

```
Positioned(
                top: 0.0,
                left: 0.0,
                child: Icon(Icons.message,
                    size: 128.0, color: Colors.greenAccent[400]), //Icon
              ),
```

Comment: but will the positioned be the same on different devices And does i get no overflow error with that  ?

Comment: you can make the amount of offset relative to screen size using media query